# URL with trailing slash in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, url-rewriting

This is my app.yaml:

```
- url: /about|/about/.*
  script: about.py
```

This is my `about.py':

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'^/about$', AboutPage),
                                      (r'^/about/$', Redirect),
                                      (r'.*', ErrorPage)],
                                        debug = True)
```

I want to redirect all requests for `/about/` to `/about`.  I'd like all other requests to be sent to the error page.

It works in the development server on localhost, but I cannot access `/about/` after I deployed the app on GAE - it just shows an empty page.

I adjusted the order of URL patterns in app.yaml.
It works now on GAE.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with Redirect and not with the URL pattern.

Comment: What Redirect does is
self.redirect('/about')
and it works well on my own machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want trailing slashes for GET requests anywhere in your application, you can implement a global redirect at the top of your app.yaml. Note that POST requests will NOT redirect, but this is ok (for me anyway) because users don't generally hand-write POST URLs.

**app.yaml**:

```
application: whatever
version: 1
api_version: 1
runtime: python

handlers:
- url: .+/ 
  script: slashmurderer.py
```

**slashmurderer.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class SlashMurdererApp(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self, url):
      self.redirect(url)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
   [('(.*)/$', SlashMurdererApp)]
)

def main():
   run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question has already been answered, but I ran into the same problem and wanted to see if there was a "lazier" solution.

If you're using the Python 2.7 runtime, then the webapp2 library is available, and I believe the following will work:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras.routes import Redirect Route

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("This is my first StackOverflow post")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    RedirectRoute('/', MainHandler, name='main', strict_slash=True),
    ('/someurl', OtherHandler),
])
```

strict_slash=True means that if the client doesn't supply the slash it will be redirected to the url with the slash (to match the first argument).

You can combine the special Route classes from webapp2_extras with normal (regex, handler) tuples as shown above. The "name" parameter is required for the constructor for RedirectRoute. More details here: [webapp2_extras documentation for RedirectRoute](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html#webapp2_extras.routes.RedirectRoute.__init__)